# Help with max raid battles?

Tags: pokemon-sword-shield

I used to be able to one hit KO all the pokemon in max raid battles, but now after i spent time progressing the game and defeating the champion i find it that i can barely even get the pokemon to half health.
 I tried a strategy where i don't take the first chance to dynamax my pokemon and instead wait later in the battle. It worked for a little bit but not too long. I dont play online and all my pokemon are over the level of 75. 
What are recommended straregies? I can provide you with my pokemon team if necessary.

Comment: Max Raid Battles have too much breadth in terms of different Pokémon and strategies for taking them down in order to fit into one question. The short answer is to boost a mon to Lv 100 for the 5* raids, but the long answer depends on which specific boss you are facing.

Comment: Well it WAS a 5 star gigantamax alcremie, but its been a day already. I dont know how to exp farm in any other games besides oras, though

Comment: One of the better ways to max a single Pokémon quickly is, unfortunately, to clear 5* raids for the EXP candy and invest all of those into a single Pokémon with good coverage. The closer you get to 100, the better the random trainers that join you will scale, and raids will go down faster and faster, giving more and more candy for leveling up.

Comment: So should i just go around the wild area looking for that camper guy that sells you exp candies, then? That could also be a good way to gather candies i guess.

Comment: I recommend against that approach. He almost never gets you the candies that give substantial EXP

Comment: Try fighting 3* and 4* raids for the time being. Their pokémon are substantially lower levelled (3* are level 40 and 4* are level 50), making it easier for your AI teammates to help. Certain 5* pokémon might be easy as well, especially ones that have x4 weaknesses you can exploit. Gigantamax pokémon are usually tailored to be the most difficult to face, unfortunately.

Comment: You can also do more champion cup battles and pokéjobs for alternative ways to gain XP.

Comment: I tried your strategie and its starting to work! Only problem is i find myself trying to buy loads of those weird rock things you toss into the dens to summon 3-4* raids.

Comment: Raids also reset every day at midnight

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're having to battle with the game-provided AI, a lot of it just comes down to luck -- some of the pokémon are almost dead weight (solrock, wobbuffet, eevee, togepi, clefairy, etc) and their fraility is more of a pain than their usefulness. These kind often don't even help breaking shields!

If you get one of these teammates, sometimes you can manage to get through (depending on how often they get targeted by the raid pokémon), otherwise if you get two often it's worth just quitting out and trying again to save yourself the time.

The AI also isn't very intelligent about type matchups either, and often you'll find it doing stuff like bringing several fire types against a water-type raid. Again, if this happens, sometimes it's just easier to reset.

From your end, the easiest thing you can do is getting your own pokémon to level 100. This will ensure far more survivability and damage output than any kind of slight improvement you get from proper natures, EVs, and so on. All raid pokémon have a maximum level of 60 (the sole exception being that event mewtwo, which is difficult enough even with 4 other humans with level 100 pokémon, let alone trying it alone!).

Ensuring your pokémon has a good type that *resists* the raid pokémon's moves is more important than making sure you can hit it super effectively. 5-star raids are more about surviving than damage, with strong shields that can even take multiple rounds to get through.

Lastly, try giving your pokémon a (non-consumable) item such as Leftovers or something that boosts the main attack you'll be using.

For specific pokémon, I'd recommend levelling your Zacian/Zamazenta and Eternatus to level 100 and seeing how well that works for you. They have very high base stats due to their legendary status, as well as signature moves that do double damage on dynamax pokémon. They should be able to handle most raid pokémon by themselves, but if you prefer not using legendaries or want to try something else, check out Silvally -- its ability to change type makes it very useful, and its Multi-Attack will change into the appropriately-typed max move if you dynamax it.

Comment: Congrats are 10k rep! :)

Comment: Wait theres a mewtwo event going on?

Comment: @Ari There was a limited time special Mewtwo event promoting the release of Pokemon: Mewtwo Strikes Back Evolution. It has since ended, but you also couldn't catch the Mewtwo

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Not even with a master ball?

Comment: Not even with a Master Ball - every time you joined the raid, you had to click through a box saying "please note that you cannot catch this Pokémon" or words to that effect.

Comment: In return for not being able to catch it, it gave out plentiful other rewards instead

Comment: What kind of rewards?

Comment: @Ari https://serebii.net/swordshield/maxraidbattles/eventden-pokemonday2020.shtml - bottom of the page

Comment: Dang, thats a lot of rewards

Comment: @Ari  btw, if this answered your question, please press the checkmark on the left so others know :)

Comment: @pyritie Oh yes, sorry, im kinda new here.